# HOW TO? Develop .NET 4.5 Application on Remote Server with IIS7.5 AND Have Debugging Capabilities

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

So I'll preface this by saying that I am very new at developing .NET applications; so please bear with me.

I would like to develop using the following scenario:
 - IDE: VS 2102 Professional on local workstation running Win7 x64
 - Web Server: IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008R2 x64
 - Website project sits in folder on remote server with a website instance configured in IIS
 - Website project and files are accessed by VS via local drive mapping.

What I am struggling with is debugging. When I develop locally (using IIS Express) debugging is as simple as pressing the "play" button on the IDE.

I have read quite a few posts today and it seems like what I should be doing is the following:

- Install and Configure Remote Debugging Tools on server
- Configure application properties to use remote server via Properties -> Web -> Use Custom Web Server

At that point I should be able to click the play button to start debugging; but no. Instead I get an error stating:

*Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on receive.*

I've researched this error and seem to have all of my settings and permissions correct. Additionally, I can use "Attach to Process..." to connect to the remote server without issue.

Just not sure what I'm doing wrong (probably everything!!!!)

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Usually that's not the normal approach.

If it's a simple application, I use the IIS Express. If it's a medium/complex application, then I use the IIS that I have installed in my computer. I don't know if you know, but you can install IIS on your development machine.

Is there any special condition for you to code in your machine, and debug in the server?